# Researching for application server supporting Java 8

Tags: java, application-server

I am currently trying to find an application server where I could deploy my Java 8 projects. As far as I am aware, due to a bug in Glassfish 4.0 it is not possible to run any Java 8 projects on it, and Tomcat supports Java up to Java 1.7. Are there any other possibilities I am not aware of?

Comment: You need to post more details about your "application". An embedded container with Spring Boot might do what you need, but it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildfly 8 supports running on java 8's JRE (don't be confused by downloads page saying "Java EE7", this is about EE spec implemented).

Comment: I checked it right now and it seems Wildfly has stable support for Java up to 1.7 ( http://wildfly.org/downloads/ )

Comment: @Niemand You are confusing Java EE 1.7 and Java SE 1.8 - they can work together.